# How do I find the probability density of a this random process as the iteration goes to infinity.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have been engaged in an intriguing exploration of a random process. I've defined this random process as a generator of a sequence of real numbers, which I refer to as ${X_n}$. These numbers belong to the set of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$. Here's a brief rundown of how this process operates:

The process begins with $X_0 = 0$. Then, for each subsequent iteration $n$, I determine the next value, $X_{n+1}$, from the current value $X_n$ with the following probabilities:

- There's a 25% probability that $X_{n+1} = X_n + 1$
- There's a 25% probability that $X_{n+1} = X_n + 2$
- There's a 25% probability that $X_{n+1} = X_n - 1$
- Finally, there's a 25% probability that $X_{n+1} = \frac{1}{4}X_n$

My aim is to understand the probability density function for the limiting distribution of $X_n$, which I refer to as $P_\infty(x)$, as the number of iterations $n$ approaches infinity.

To further this understanding, I have conducted several simulations. For these, I've estimated the probabilities for $X_n$ to fall within specified half-open intervals $(n, n+0.5]$, and have documented the results below:

| Interval | Estimated Probability |
| --- | --- |
| (-6.5, -6] | 0.0023 |
| (-6, -5.5] | 0.0054 |
| (-5.5, -5] | 0.0118 |
| (-5, -4.5] | 0.0071 |
| (-4.5, -4] | 0.0054 |
| (-4, -3.5] | 0.0097 |
| (-3.5, -3] | 0.0295 |
| (-3, -2.5] | 0.02 |
| (-2.5, -2] | 0.0144 |
| (-2, -1.5] | 0.0337 |
| (-1.5, -1] | 0.0749 |
| (-1, -0.5] | 0.044 |
| (-0.5, 0] | 0.0443 |
| (0, 0.5] | 0.2699 |
| (0.5, 1] | 0.0895 |
| (1, 1.5] | 0.046 |
| (1.5, 2] | 0.0445 |
| (2, 2.5] | 0.0743 |
| (2.5, 3] | 0.0343 |
| (3, 3.5] | 0.0183 |
| (3.5, 4] | 0.015 |
| (4, 4.5] | 0.0272 |
| (4.5, 5] | 0.0141 |
| (5, 5.5] | 0.0074 |
| (5.5, 6] | 0.0067 |
| (6, 6.5] | 0.0091 |
| (6.5, 7] | 0.0048 |
| (7, 7.5] | 0.0022 |

I am now attempting to utilize these findings to formulate the probability density function $P_\infty(x)$ for the limiting distribution.

By assuming the probability $p_{n}(x)$ of the process being at a certain number $x$ on the $n^{th}$ term is equal to the sum of the probabilities of all possible locations it could have been in the preceding $(n-1)^{th}$ term, we can express this relationship as:

$$P_{n}(x) = \frac{1}{4} \left( p_{n-1}(x-1) + p_{n-1}(x-2) + p_{n-1}(x+1) + p_{n-1}(\frac{x}{4}) \right)$$

My goal is to discover a limiting distribution $P_\infty(x)$ as $n \to \infty$. I acknowledge that the probability of being at any specific number approaches 0, but if I select a range of numbers, the probability that it lands within that range is non-zero. I want to find this probability density function, which I refer to as:

$$P_\infty(x)$$ which when you take the intergral between a and b you get the probablity the number is between $a$ and $b$.

Assuming this limit exists, we can express the limiting distribution in terms of itself with a specific property. This property should hold true for any two real numbers $a$ and $b$:

$$\int_{a}^{b} P_{\infty}(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{4} \left( \int_{a+1}^{b+1} P_{\infty}(x) \, dx + \int_{a-1}^{b-1} P_{\infty}(x) \, dx + \int_{a-2}^{b-2} P_{\infty}(x)\, dx + \int_{4a}^{4b} P_{\infty}(x) \, dx \right)$$ and $$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P_{\infty}(x) \, dx = 1$$
The challenge at hand is to identify a $P_\infty(x)$ that satisfies this property.

So, here's my question: Can anyone provide guidance on how to determine a $P_\infty(x)$ that satisfies this property?

Comment: The process is very chaotic mostly because one of the "random action" is to multiply by $\frac{1}{4}$. If we were allowed to exclude this action, then this process would be fully determined. Considering all the action, we could define $X_i$ as the position at the $i$-th step of the process and $X$ as its limit (convergence in distribution). Then $X\in D=\mathbb{Z}\cup I$, where: $I = \{\frac{z}{4^p}: z\in\mathbb{Z},p\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Knowing the density function of $X$ is equivalent to associate for all $t\in D$ the probability $P(X=t)$ which is very complicated I think.

Comment: @LucaOnnis I believe this fact I found about the PDF might help $$\int_{a}^{b}(P_{\infty }(x))dx = \frac{1}{4}(\int_{a+1}^{b+1}(P_{\infty }(x))dx+\int_{a-1}^{b-1}(P_{\infty }(x))dx+\int_{a-2}^{b-2}(P_{\infty }(x))dx+\int_{4a}^{4b}(P_{\infty }(x))dx)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\eqd{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
This certainly isn't a complete answer, which I'm guessing is likely to be rather difficult.

The process you describe is a [homogeneous Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Variations) whose state space is the entire set of [Dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), $\ \Bbb{D}\ $.  Its transition probabilites are given by
$$
P\left(X_{n+1}=r\,\right|\left.\,X_n=q\right)=\cases{\frac{1}{4}&if $\ r\in\left\{q-1,q+1,q+2,\frac{q}{4}\right\}$ ,\\
0&otherwise,}
$$
and its initial state is  $\ X_0=0\ $.  It's not difficult to show that every state of this chain is *transient*, which means that with probability $1$ it will only be visited at most a finite number of times.  It also means that $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}P\big(X_n=x\big)=0\ $ for *any* $\ x\ $ (whether $\ x\in\Bbb{D}\ $ or not).  It's therefore not obvious (not to me, at least) that the distribution function, $\ F_{X_n}\ $, of $\ X_n\ ,$ defined by
$$
F_{X_n}(x)\eqd P\big(X_n\le x\big)\ ,
$$
will necessarily converge in any sense to a limiting distribution. And even if it does, it's not at all clear that any limiting distribution will necessarily have a density with respect to Lebesgue measure.  That is, it might happen that $\ F_{X_n}\ $ does converge in some sense to some distribution, $\ F_\infty\ $, as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $ but that there doesn't exist any integrable function $\ \varphi:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}\ $ such that
$$
F_\infty(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\varphi(u)\,du\ .
$$

If $\ e_n\eqd E(X_n)\ $, then $\ e_n\ $ must satify the recursion,
\begin{align}
e_n&=0.25\big(e_{n-1}+2+e_{n-1}+1+e_{n-1}-1+0.25e_{n-1}\big)\\
&=\left(\frac{13}{16}\right)e_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}\\
\end{align}
which can be written as
\begin{align}
\left(e_n-\frac{8}{3}\right)&=\left(\frac{13}{16}\right)\left(e_{n-1}-\frac{8}{3}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{13}{16}\right)^n\left(e_0-\frac{8}{3}\right)\\
&={-}\frac{8}{3}\left(\frac{13}{16}\right)^n\ .
\end{align}
Thus, $\ e_n=\frac{8}{3}\left(1-\left(\frac{13}{16}\right)^n\right)\rightarrow\frac{8}{3}\ $ as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $.

Likewise, if $\ d_n\eqd E\big(X_n^2)\ $, then
\begin{align}
d_n&=0.25E\left(\big(X_{n-1}+2\big)^2+(X_{n-1}+1)^2+(X_{n-1}-1)^2+\frac{X_{n-1}^2}{16}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{49}{64}\right)d_{n-1}+e_{n-1}+\frac{3}{2}\\
&=\left(\frac{49}{64}\right)d_{n-1}+\left(e_{n-1}-\frac{8}{3}\right)+\frac{25}{6}\ ,
\end{align}
which can be written as
\begin{align}
d_n-\frac{160}{9}&=\frac{49}{64}\left(d_{n-1}-\frac{160}{9}\right)-\frac{8}{3}\left(\frac{13}{16}\right)^{n-1}\ ,
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
d_n-\frac{160}{9}+\frac{512}{9}\left(\frac{13}{16}\right)^n&=\frac{49}{64}\left(d_{n-1}-\frac{160}{9}+\frac{512}{9}\left(\frac{13}{16}\right)^{n-1}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{49}{64}\right)^n\left(d_0-\frac{160}{9}+\frac{512}{9}\right)\ ,
\end{align}
from which it follows that
\begin{align}
d_n&=\frac{160}{9}+\frac{352}{9}\left(\frac{49}{64}\right)^n-\frac{512}{9}\left(\frac{13}{16}\right)^n\\
&\rightarrow\frac{160}{9}
\end{align}
as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $.  Thus, $\ \text{Var}\big(X_n\big)=d_n-e_n^2\rightarrow\frac{160}{9}-\frac{64}{9}=\frac{32}{3}\ $ as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $.

The way in which the mean of $\ X_n\ $ and $\ X_n^2\ $ can be shown to converge as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $ suggests that it might be possible to do the same for any other moment $\ E\big(X_n^m\big)\ $ of $\ X_n\ $, and hence also for its [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)),
$$
E\left(e^{itX_n}\right)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(it)^m}{m!}E\big(X_n^m\big)\ ,
$$
and then use [Levy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem) and [Bochner's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem) theorems to deduce that the distribution functions of $\ X_n\ $ converge to a limit that's also a distribution function. If it is possible, however, it  seems to me that the details are likely to be rather messy.

**Update**

I've just realised that you can use a version of your recurrence to obtain what the characteristic function of the limiting distribution must be *if* it exists.  Proving that the distributions converge to a limiting one might therefore not be quite as hard as I thought.

Let
$$
\varphi_n(t)\eqd E\left(e^{itX_n}\right)
$$
be the characteristic function of the distribution of $\ X_n\ $.  Then we have
\begin{align}
\varphi_n(t)&=\frac{1}{4}\left(E\left(e^{it\big(X_{n-1}-1\big)}\right)+E\left(e^{it\big(X_{n-1}+1\big)}\right)+E\left(e^{it\big(X_{n-1}+2\big)}\right)+E\left(e^{\frac{itX_{n-1}}{4}}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{\big(e^{-it}+e^{it}+e^{2it}\big)\varphi_{n-1}(t)+\varphi_{n-1}\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)}{4}\ .
\end{align}
Thus, if $\ \varphi_n\ $ converges pointwise, to a limit $\ \varphi_\infty\ $, then the latter must satisfy the equation
$$
\varphi_\infty=\frac{\big(e^{-it}+e^{it}+e^{2it}\big)\varphi_\infty(t)+\varphi_\infty\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)}{4}\ ,
$$
or, equivalently,
\begin{align}
\varphi_\infty(t)&=\frac{\varphi_\infty\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)}{4-\big(e^{-it}+e^{it}+e^{2it}\big)}\\
&=\frac{\varphi_\infty\left(\frac{t}{4^2}\right)}{\left(4-\big(e^{-it}+e^{it}+e^{2it}\big)\right)\left(4-\left(e^{-\frac{it}{4}}+e^{\frac{it}{4}}+e^{\frac{2it}{4}}\right)\right)}\\
&=\varphi_\infty\left(\frac{t}{4^{n+1}}\right)\prod_{j=0}^n\frac{1}{\left(4-\left(e^{-\frac{it}{4^j}}+e^{\frac{it}{4^j}}+e^{\frac{2it}{4^j}}\right)\right)}\ .
\end{align}
Now if the distributions of $\ X_n\ $ converge to a limiting distribution $\ F_\infty\ $, then $\ \varphi_\infty\left(\frac{t}{4^{n+1}}\right)\ $ will converge to
\begin{align}
\varphi_\infty(0)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e ^{i\,0\,x}\,dF_\infty(x)\\
&=1\ ,
\end{align}
and it's not hard to show that the product $$
\prod_{j=0}^n\frac{1}{\left(4-\left(e^{-\frac{it}{4^j}}+e^{\frac{it}{4^j}}+e^{\frac{2it}{4^j}}\right)\right)}
$$
has a finite, non-zero limit as $\ n\rightarrow\infty $.  Thus, *if* the limiting distribution exists, its characteristic function must be
$$
\varphi_\infty(t)=\prod_{j=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(4-\left(e^{-\frac{it}{4^j}}+e^{\frac{it}{4^j}}+e^{\frac{2it}{4^j}}\right)\right)}\ .
$$